# sort nsarray by second word. (by surname in "firstname surname" kind of strings array)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting

I am having nsarray of strings like "fistname surname". Now I want to sort that strings array by second word i.e. by surname.
I used this method

```
NSArray *sortedArray=[[teachersList allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSLog(@"After %@",sortedArray);
```

But it sorts array on first word.

And i am also having elements or strings with firstname only means only first word.

So how to do this?

Edit

@Janak Nirmal

My modified code is:

```
while([resultSet next])
{
    [teachersList setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[resultSet stringForColumn:@"first_name"],[resultSet stringForColumn:@"last_name"]] forKey:[resultSet stringForColumn:@"email_id"]];
    [emailList addObject:[resultSet stringForColumn:@"email_id"]];
    appDelegate.grade=[resultSet stringForColumn:@"grade"];

}

    //NSArray *sortedArrays=[[teachersList allValues] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


   NSArray *sortedArray = [[teachersList allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord = [[[[(Teacher*)a name] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord = [[[[(Teacher*)b name] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
        return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord];
    }];
```

but i m getting following error

[__NSCFString name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do sort like,

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [teacherList sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord = [[[[(Teacher*)a name] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
    NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord = [[[[(Teacher*)b name] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
    return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord];
}];
//Assuming in above you have atleast 2 words in name 
//i.e. objectAtIndex:1 doesn't fail or you need to put condition 
//there according to your needs
```

Assuming your model structure as below,

```
@interface Teacher : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

**EDIT**

As your [teacherList allValues] would be directly holding string values you should write it as below

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [[teachersList allValues] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *firstTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)a) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
    NSString *secondTeacher2ndWord = [[[((NSString*)b) componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1] lowercaseString];
    return [firstTeacher2ndWord compare:secondTeacher2ndWord];
}];
```

Above code will give you array of all values directly in sorted manner.

Comment: thanks, but i want to know how will it work with multiple elements means thirdteachers , fourthteacher etc.

Comment: @VirendraRavalji thats just variable name, it will loop through all the elements in your array. You can always give different names at them e.g. firstModel2ndWord and secondModel2ndWord check the [sortedArrayUsingComparator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

Comment: @VirendraRavalji you should add your code in your question not in my answer. It got rejected by the reviewers.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, happy to give something back to community :D

Comment: hie janak I am facing new issue with sorting ,I have posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012740/sort-on-nsdictionary-is-giving-different-result-than-sort-on-nsarray

Answer (score 2):

because you have single string and it will always start to compare from "`first name`"

> so you have to first split the string by space

```
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

from here you have to build a dictionary of name with this split string like

```
@{@"FirstName" : listItems[0], "FirstName" : listItems[1]}
```

and `add into array and then you can sort` this

```
NSArray *keys = [theDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareMethod:)];
```